# Lock down certain member groups in the CP so other members can’t delete them?

Tags: members, control-panel, delete

Does anyone know if there is there a way to lock down certain member groups in the CP so other members can’t delete member accounts belonging to those member groups?

I have a specific member group, let's call them 'Administrators' which need to be able to create members and delete members in another member group, called 'Customers'. But I don't want the 'Administrators' to be able to delete members in other member groups.

Does that make sense. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean you don't want Admins to be able to delete the actual member _groups?_ If that is the case then you're in good shape. Only Superadmins can create or delete member _groups_. Or are you instead interested in preventing deletion of the individual member accounts _in_ certain member groups?

Comment: What I need to do, is restrict any members of one member group '_Administrators_' so they can only delete members from another specific member group '_Customers_'. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Unfortunately it seems that giving a member group the _"Can delete members"_ permission gives them permission to delete any member! Unless I am missing something I think you will need a custom extension to handle this.

Comment: Yep, what I thought sadly. Do you know of any extensions that would make this possible?

Comment: No, but it could be done really simply with some logic to check if the deleted member isn't in a protected group. I'm not sure there is a suitable hook, though. The only hook that comes close is [cp_members_member_delete_end](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/cp/members/index.html#cp-members-member-delete-end), but that is fired too late and the members would already be deleted!

Comment: Alex, found a candidate in member model, [hook member\_delete](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/global/member_model/index.html#member-delete)

Comment: Okay, that's beyond me tbh. I'll see if GDmac's solution will work okay for me/the client. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Alex mentions, when a user has "Can delete members" rights, he/she can delete any member.

A different approach would be to, not allow to delete members, but to only allow users to be moved to a member group with no (login) rights at all. You can restrict to which group a member can be assigned by setting the group to "locked". If needed, the restricted member group could regularly be purged by a super-admin.

Comment: Thanks GDmac, that makes sense and could be a reasonable workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I think GDmac's answer is the way to go. But I thought it would be fun to start on an extension....

This seems to do the trick, though it is pretty bare-bones (no settings, not much detail in the message shown to the user).

Using the [`member_delete`](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/global/member_model/index.html#member-delete) hook:

```
public function member_delete($member_ids)
{

    // Array of member group_ids for which to restrict delete permissions
    $supervised_member_groups = array('7');

    // Array of member group_ids for wich deletion is disallowed
    $protected_member_groups = array('5','6');

    // The group_id of the current admin
    $current_admin_group_id = ee()->session->userdata('group_id');

    // Check if the current admin is in the supervised member group
    if (in_array($current_admin_group_id, $supervised_member_groups))
    {
        // Generate an array of group_ids to which the deleted member(s) belong(s)
        $member_groups = array();
        $query = ee()->db->select('group_id')->where_in('member_id', $member_ids)->get('members');
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) 
        {
            array_push($member_groups, $row->group_id);
        }

        // Check if the deleted member belongs to one of the protected member groups 
        // and if so throw an error
        $overlap = count(array_intersect($protected_member_groups, $member_groups));            
        if ($overlap) show_error('You are attempting to delete a member from a protected group. Please adjust your selection.');
    }

    return $member_ids;
}
```

[Gist with full extension](https://gist.github.com/twosixcode/cae6eec0ae3c963e5d07)

Comment: for ee 2.7+ you probably need to restore_xid(), otherwise, the xid of the form will probably be invalid. nice idea for an add-on with settings screen etc.